# Is asking for an image segmentation algorithm (with example problem) on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Am I allowed to ask this [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22261/image-segmentation-algorithm) on Stack Overflow, or is off-topic for this website ?

It is a question where I am looking for an algorithm to segment the hair in a picture very precisely.

Comment: I believe it would be too broad. *I just want to know if someone can give me some efficient algorithms to segment the hair on this image for example without cutting it and so on* is not really actionable in our format.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ok, thank you very much

Comment: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/748634/ ?

Comment: that is very kind of you, @Will

Comment: That was five seconds in a search engine.  You should try that sometimes.

Comment: @Will trust me, I have downloaded lot of PDF files about this, I read may be 25 articles in total but they do not show satisfactory results for my needs

Comment: Ah!  Information like that is very useful to put in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK, since you've tried a number of algorithms. You might want to add how the used algorithms failed to produce the desired result.

Also consider that you already posted it elsewhere - cross-posting is frowned upon.

It would have been a fine question for Stack Overflow a few years ago, but now people might want to close it as it is a bit broad, and arguably opinion-based. To avoid this, it should help if you explain a bit more about the things you've already tried.
On Stack Overflow, asking how the application of a particular algorithm could be improved - how to parameterize the algorithm correctly - would probably do better.

But since you've already posted this on [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), maybe it's better to just edit the question over there. I am not familiar with the culture over there, however, so I cannot judge which edits would help best on that site.